# Camel and Cache LifeCycle

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, ehcache

I have troubles with the management of ehCache lifecycle within Camel. I have routes that are defined in Spring DSL. I can load them dynamically through my application. In the initial load of  the camel context, the cache works marvelously. Yet, if I stop the camel context and try to restart it, the ehCache doesn't restart. I have no EhCache custom configuration. This means that the whole lifecycle is actually managed by camel-cache.

Here is the exception I get when I try to access ehcache after restarting the camel context:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The demo Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4009) ~[ehcache2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2717) ~[ehcache-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
```

Is there a way to have better control on the EhCache lifecycle management so that I can restart the cache when the route is restarted?

Along those lines, is there a way to setup the cache such that it is globally visible in the JVM as opposed to being tied to one camel context? In other words, is there a ay to setup ehCache such that I can restart camel contexts without shuting down EhCache?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using spring's support for [EHCache](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-ehcache) which shall remove dependency of managing EHCache by Camel. What I mean is use Spring to manage EHCache rather than Camel so that starting/stopping of camelContext/routes won't affect EHCache. Check the JMX support provided by EHCache to have your other requirement about global visibility. For enabling JMX support you need to use the EHCache management service as below :

```
<bean id="ehCacheManagementService" class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService" init-method="init" lazy-init="false">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" factory-method="getInstance"/>
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.support.JmxUtils" factory-method="locateMBeanServer"/>
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg value="true"/>
  <constructor-arg value="true"/>
  <constructor-arg value="true"/>
  <constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>
```